# ANSIBLE "ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set"

Tags: linux, centos, red-hat, ansible

Tengo una VM CENTOS 7 con ansible instalado, y estoy tratando de instalar en un RED HAT 8 el servicio HTTPD con ansible.

Contenido ficheros:

"hosts"

```
[ubuntuserver]
192.168.1.51
[redhat]
192.168.56.102
```

"playbook.yaml"

```
[root@centos7 ansible]# cat playbook.yaml
---
- hosts: redhat
- remote_user: root
  tasks:
     - name: instalar apache
       yum: name=httpd
[root@centos7 ansible]#
```

Error que consigo:

[image: Mensaje Error]

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en el playbook, el guion de remote_user no deberia estar ahi:

```yml
    ---
    - hosts: redhat
      remote_user: root
      tasks:
         - name: instalar apache
           yum: name=httpd
```